# Change passphrase of SSH key stored in the gpg-agent

Tags: ssh, gpg, ssh-agent, gpg-agent

How do I change the passphrase of an SSH key that is stored in the gpg-agent?

Comment: You don't. The key that's stored in the agent is *already unlocked*. What you can do is change the passphrase of the key on disk and unload the key from the agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to change the passphrase for a key that you use for a longer time, consider replacing the key entirely. Usually it's not a big effort and key rotation is a good routine.

Now to the question: While you can change the passphrase of the ssh-key stored in you `~/.ssh` directory with
`ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`, I think the gpg-agent makes a copy. To change the passphrase of that copy,

1. run `gpg-connect-agent`
2. Inside of this prompt, run `keyinfo --ssh-list --ssh-fpr`. This will list your keys:

```
S KEYINFO 077241111111111111111111111111111119D506 D - - 1 P MD5:36:a3:62:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:1f:45:6e - S
OK
```

3. Copy the id after the `KEYINFO` of the key you want to change the password for and run `passwd <id>`
   (so `passwd 077241111111111111111111111111111119D506` in the example above) and follow the process
4. Leave the agent prompt by typing `/bye`